# try and catch not working

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a problem with my try/catch statement. I know it's probably an easy fix but I'm new to java.
Here I want the console to prompt the user to add their initial deposit, for example, if I input something like "hello" the program will crash rather than ask again? thanks

here are the errors I'm receiving:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
at

java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

```
System.out.println("Please enter an initial deposit:");
            try{  

                deposit.add(keyboard.nextInt());

            }catch(NumberFormatException e){

                System.out.println("Invalid input");

            System.out.println("Please enter an account number:");
            accountNumber.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
```

Comment: missing a closing bracket? `catch(NumberFormatException e){ System.out.println("Invalid input");} /*...*/ System.out.println("Please enter an account number:");
`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If yes, what are they?

Comment: Did you check what exception did you get? For instance, if you get Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException, then you cannot catch using NumberFormatException?

Comment: You need to add explicit code to ask the user to try again?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: @HelpMe-ICantJava: You should "edit" this information into the question, because it is easily missed in the length comment list not everyone will want to read through.

Answer (score 2):

according to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int))

method nextInt throws **InputMismatchException** not NumberFormatException

write:

```
catch(InputMismatchException e){
       ....
```

UPDATE:
I use this snippet and inputing number works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter an initial deposit:");

    try {
        int numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numberEntered);

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

        System.out.println("Invalid input");

        System.out.println("Please enter an account number:");
    } finally {
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

console:

```
Please enter an initial deposit:
55
55

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This improves it a little bit. it actually shows "invalid input"

however, continues to "please enter an account number" and then crashes with 'Exception in thread'

Comment: I extended the answer, hope it helps you debug your code

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not getting the exception you have caught. On the contrary, you are getting InputMismatchException.
2. Since you are trying to get input again within catch statement, where you must be supplying invalid input again. But then who is catching this exception? No one. Hence, your program will exit. Also, I don't see any code beyond that line. Hence, it may be a normal exit too.

Answer (score 0):

First one bracket is missing. I think after the println("Invalid Input");.

If it is still not working try to catch all kinds of errors
`catch(Exeption e){...}`